# How can I upload a file via ssh to my server with a different port then 22?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, port, scp

I try to upload a file via ssh to my server:

```
scp -p 2222 user@myhost:/Users/myuser/mypage/myrepository.git
```

I get the error message:

> ssh: connect to host myhost port 22: Connection refused

How do I specify scp to use port 2222?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
scp -P 2222 -r myrepository.git user@myhost:/Users/myuser/mypage/
```

Answer (score 1):

scp uses an upper-case P to specify the port.
Try this instead:

```
scp -P 2222 user@myhost:/Users/myuser/mypage/myrepository.git
```